# easyadmin 3.3 groupby in AssociationField

Tags: symfony5, easyadmin3

I'm using **symfony 5.1** and **easyadmin 3.3**, I know I'm not updated but now I can't update right now.

I have a relationship **1:m** between **Product** and **Dealer**, in the **ProductCrudController** I have a **Dealer** as a **AssociationField** and I have a **query_builder** to show only a specific group of **Dealer** what they are showing in a **select2** field. The Dealers can be a diferent zones and I would like group those Dealers by zone.

I have looked at several articles but anything like this.

This is my code, but I don't know how to group them.

```
// in ProductCrudController
$fields[] = AssociationField::new('dealer')
        ->setFormTypeOptions([
        'query_builder' => function (DealerRepository $repository) {
          return $repository->findByDepartament($this->getUser());
        },
      ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's really the best way to resolve this but at least it worked for me. I didn't use '**AssociationField**' like I'd though previously, I get the array then group by zone and use a '**ChoiceField**'.

This is my code:

```
$repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(Dealer::class);
$result = $repository->findByDepartament($this->getUser());
$choice = [];

foreach ($result as $d){
  $choice[$d->getZone()->getName()][$d->getName()] = $d;
}

$fields[] = ChoiceField::new('dealer')
    ->setChoices($choice);
```